# load all child node values from all firebase users into collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch all the same child values from all users in my Firebase DB, and am having some issues. In my specific use case, I want all the "Planning"/"planning" child values from all my users to load into a collectionView. I have been able to manually map to the child Value of "Planning" directly, but I had to use the currentUser.uid, which of course only gave me the current logged in user's "Planning" Values (so not all the users "Planning" values). Again, I would like to load the collectionView with all the "Planning" values in my entire Firebase DB. Thanks in advance for any help...I have been stuck on this for a while!

[image]

// JSON from Firebase

```
{
  "users" : {
    "CmtuebwVrmOG3n4uSsIK1b4FsSN2" : {
      "Planning" : {
        "-Kl_xoIEXw1HqbL9-JDA" : {
          "addedBy" : "CmtuebwVrmOG3n4uSsIK1b4FsSN2",
          "planning" : "Napa Valley, CA, USA",
          "timestamp" : 1.49635932283732E9
        }
      },
      "name" : "Daniel Meier",
    },
    "TFN8NFSPfdMBJQ15iDhhRSRVUcV2" : {
      "Planning" : {
        "-KlW0Tw3ZMnTDvHgN-NM" : {
          "addedBy" : "TFN8NFSPfdMBJQ15iDhhRSRVUcV2",
          "planning" : "Patagonia",
          "timestamp" : 1.496276397864224E9
        },
        "-KlW0nqdABHlMa7Lj31X" : {
          "addedBy" : "TFN8NFSPfdMBJQ15iDhhRSRVUcV2",
          "planning" : "Cabo San Lucas, Baja California Sur, Mexico",
          "timestamp" : 1.496276483532304E9
        },
        "-KlW1sc4t-jUKqXxQpuf" : {
          "addedBy" : "TFN8NFSPfdMBJQ15iDhhRSRVUcV2",
          "planning" : "Vancouver, BC, Canada",
          "timestamp" : 1.496276765230323E9
        },
        "-KlW4aCDUXKBqnxKoU04" : {
          "addedBy" : "TFN8NFSPfdMBJQ15iDhhRSRVUcV2",
          "planning" : "Santiago, Santiago Metropolitan Region, Chile",
          "timestamp" : 1.496277476204581E9
        },
        "-KlW6BQpoO4wIWsTJcnC" : {
          "addedBy" : "TFN8NFSPfdMBJQ15iDhhRSRVUcV2",
          "planning" : "Istanbul, İstanbul, Turkey",
          "timestamp" : 1.496277894928425E9
        },
        "-KlWFHKBKrEd-z8qM9gz" : {
          "addedBy" : "TFN8NFSPfdMBJQ15iDhhRSRVUcV2",
          "planning" : "Lyon, France",
          "timestamp" : 1.496280278376963E9
        },
        "-Kl_wL42PfG_MtvkwWpk" : {
          "addedBy" : "TFN8NFSPfdMBJQ15iDhhRSRVUcV2",
          "planning" : "Kentucky, USA",
          "timestamp" : 1.496358936906602E9
        }
      },
      "name" : "Dan Meier",
    },
    "jtnJjBCW9mdkvXy7DV7ox1DUvzO2" : {
      "Planning" : {
        "-Kl_xgDG-7CpdQyvrbM5" : {
          "addedBy" : "jtnJjBCW9mdkvXy7DV7ox1DUvzO2",
          "planning" : "Hong Kong Island, Hong Kong",
          "timestamp" : 1.496359289751177E9
        },
        "-Kl_xi0vCO-BZ10AMua3" : {
          "addedBy" : "jtnJjBCW9mdkvXy7DV7ox1DUvzO2",
          "planning" : "London, UK",
          "timestamp" : 1.496359297153533E9
        }
      },
      "name" : "Daniel Meier",
    }
  }
}
```

// NSObject modal object

```
class CurrentPlanner: SafeJsonObjectPlanner {

    var planningPlace: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        super.init()

        self.planningPlace = dictionary["planning"] as? String

        setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
    }
}
```

// baseCell CollectionViewCell class

```
class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }    
}
```

// function to fetch Planning values from Firebase

```
var plannedPlaces = [CurrentPlanner]()

   func fetchPlanningPlaces() {

        let baseRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")
        baseRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let planningCell = CurrentPlanner(dictionary: dictionary)
                self.plannedPlaces.append(planningCell)
                print(self.plannedPlaces)
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)

        //this will crash because of background thread, so lets use dispatch_async to fix
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

// setup collectionView

```
 override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()

        fetchPlanningPlaces()

        // ...

        collectionView.register(BasePlanningCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return plannedPlaces.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! BasePlanningCell
        cell.currentPlanner = plannedPlaces[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of making a "Planning" node inside each user, make it outside of the "users" node completely. Having done that, this problem will be easier to solve and reading from Firebase will be faster.

Comment: Ok , I get that. I also want to add the users name and profilePic to each "Planning" collectionViewCell. So would it still be better to add the "profileImageUrl" to each "Planning" node and load the profileImageUrl for every Planning node called? Also, is it sage to say it is generally safer to have only 1 level of values under each node (i.e. for the user's "uid" node only have "name:" "email:" and "profileImageUrl")?

Comment: Don't put that info into "Planning". It belongs in the profile. Instead, use the "addedBy" ID as a reference to a profile from the "users" node. Use it like a key, and grab the profile info corresponding with that key in "users". Also, regarding how many levels deep you should go, refer to Firebase's guide to structuring your data (the flatter the better): https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Comment: Ok, thats what I figured. Thanks!

Comment: @user3708224 Can you please post your full code solution ?